# Construct my own character classes

Tags: shell, text-processing, regular-expression

I want to construct my own character class in a script, then modify (and use) it, for example:

1. `[:myclass:]` contains `a`, `*`, `\n` *(as linefeed)* and `[WHITESPACE]`.
2. I want to add all characters to `[:myclass:]` from `[:alnum:]`.
3. I want to remove the `p` character and the entire `[:upper:]` class from `[:myclass:]`

The preferred solution doesn't depend on scripting languages. If you want to, use `bash`.

---

Bonus question: how to store this systemwide? Whenever I boot, `[:myclass:]` has to be available.

Comment: I don't know very much about this but you could probably accomplish this with a custom `LC_CTYPE` setting.  It may require defining a custom locale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid that the list of character classes is hard-coded in the C library (e.g. in GNU libc, in the `build_charclass` function in [`posix/regcomp.c`](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=posix/regcomp.c;h=373a52ecffebc127b7a776371f407d18623580d2;hb=HEAD)). The only way to extend it would be to recompile the C library.

You can customize the contents of each existing class in a locale definition.

In most cases, it should be good enough to build your regexp as a string:

```
myclass='a*[:alnum:][:space:]'
regexp="[$myclass]"
```

You can't subtract characters from a category this way. And take care if adding `]` or `-` or `\` to respect the syntax of character classes in your language's regexes.

Comment: Excellent solution of you - as always. :) I think I will try both of them, but the second seems way more easier. I could even add a MYCLASS environment variable to the init scripts.